# Why does my crawler with BeautifulSoup, not show results?

Tags: python, web-crawler

This is the code that I wrote.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def code_search(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://kindai.ndl.go.jp/search/searchResult?searchWord=朝鲜&facetOpenedNodeIds=&featureCode=&viewRestrictedList=&pageNo=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'item-link'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            page += 1

code_search(2)
```

---

My pycharm version is pycharm-community-5.0.3 for mac.

It just says:

`"Process finished with exit code 0"`

But there should be some results if I have wrote the code accordingly...

Please help me out here!

Comment: First at all, you forgot `print`. And then, what do you want to get?

Comment: No `return` no `print`...how do you expect to see output?

Comment: And What's you expected output?..

Comment: @spitfire, you should maybe start with a tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/, there is nothing at all that could possibly be outputted running your code, even if you called it with a print all you would see is None

Comment: I was trying to get bunch of URLs, Thanks! "Print" helped. Now output showed, Thanks guys~

Comment: Shift your `page += 1` to the left. You want to do this for every page, not every anchor `a` on a page

Answer (score 0):

You have no `print` statements - so the program doesn't output anything.

Add some print statements. For example, if you output the link, do this:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'item-link'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)
        page += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you want to archieve with the web crawler. The first observation is that nothing is printed.

The following code prints the URL and all links found on the URL.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def code_search(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://kindai.ndl.go.jp/search/searchResult?searchWord=朝鲜&facetOpenedNodeIds=&featureCode=&viewRestrictedList=&pageNo=' + str(page)
        print("Current URL:", url)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'item-link'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print("Found URL:", href)
            page += 1

code_search(2)
```

It is also possible to let the method return all found URLs and then print the results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def code_search(max_pages):
    page = 1
    urls = []
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://kindai.ndl.go.jp/search/searchResult?searchWord=朝鲜&facetOpenedNodeIds=&featureCode=&viewRestrictedList=&pageNo=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'item-link'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            urls.append(href)
            page += 1
    return urls

print("Found URLs:", code_search(2))
```